# Are the android names in the Alien franchise in alphabetical order on purpose?

Tags: alien-franchise

In the first four Alien films, we were introduced first to Ash, then Bishop (and then Bishop II) and then Call. In Prometheus we then met David. Is this just an in-joke that the androids started from A through to C? And is David somewhat of an anachronism in the sense that Prometheus is widely regarded as a prequel to Alien?

Comment: Just to throw a spanner in the works, the synthetic that appears toward the end of Alien³ was called "Bishop II".

Comment: I thought it was the original person who Bishop was modelled on? Taken from wiki: "Lance Henriksen as the voice of the damaged Bishop android, as well as playing a character **credited as Bishop II**, who appears in the film's final scenes, **claiming to be the human designer of the android**, who wants the Alien Queen that was growing inside Ripley for use in Weyland-Yutani's bioweapons division. **Revealed as Michael Bishop Weyland in the game Aliens: Colonial Marines**." As well, **Michael (Lance Henriksen), also known as "Bishop II", is a scientist in the employ of Weyland-Yutani**.

Comment: Indeed. And I supposed it's fair to say that he wasn't a major character. I was just pointing out that in terms of android appearances in the films it goes **A**sh, **B**ishop, **B**ishop II, **C**ale, **D**avid since Bishop II was [palpably not a human](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/avp/images/b/b2/I_am_not_a_droid.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140831202403).

Answer (score 9):

### Yes

The people working on the franchise recently, at least, are aware of (and actively adhering to) this trend. 
From [an interview](http://comicsalliance.com/kelly-sue-deconnick-dark-horse-comics-prometheus-interview/) with Kelly Sue DeConnick, who wrote an official comic miniseries that follows *Prometheus*:

> Comics Alliance: Is there an android whose name starts with the letter E?
>
> KSD: There is!
>
> CA: Good. I’m so pleased. Because we have to have the
>   alphabetical-order androids.
>
> KSD: **We have solved that problem for you. Scratched that itch.**

Indeed, the android was named [Elden](http://weyland.wikia.com/wiki/Elden).

As for David's name being an anachronism, why should it be? The androids appear to be named in release order of the films, not in-universe  chronological order